# ObReferenceObject Vs File Deletion

Tags: c++, c, windows

In my device driver I reference a file object (using ObReferenceObject) and then I try to delete that file normally and the file is deleted. I was actually waiting for a STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE value but it's not the case.

Is a file deleted even if its ReferenceCount isn't equal to 0 ?

Comment: Which version of Windows?  Does the file object allow `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`?  Where did the file object come from?